# facebook analytics data "download this data in a CSV"

Tags: export, facebook-analytics

I have a task - download facebook analytics data.
I need this kind of data (Download this data in a CSV file) [image]

The data I see here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export
Is different.
I was trying to apply web-console in the analytics website to check the request/response, but no luck.
Is there any way to download it somehow via API?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API do download hourly active users in Facebook Analytics - these reports are accessible via the UI only.